# How to remove frame header from a Window in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, extjs4

I am using an Ext.window.Window and i don't wanna the frame in my window.

The window has the property 'frameHeader' (true or false) but i change this and my window doesn't change anything..

What i can do to remove the window header ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple options:

```
title: '',
frame: false,
```

If that's not something that you want - please provide a sketch of what result are you trying to achieve.

Comment: i have to put 'true' in frame value but the header border stays there. it's possible to remove the header border?

Answer (score 5):

Use property `header` instead, like:

```
header: false
```

It will remove the header

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for the preventHeader option. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-preventHeader

```
preventHeader: true
```

This will completely disable the header though and will remove the ability to move/close the window.

Comment: If you want to hide header you should use preventHeader: true

Comment: Haha logic fail there. Cheers @Oleg